# Ordering, grouping and filtering SQL result sets

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got a number of 'containers' in a database, each of which contains zero or more items. Each item has a name, score, timestamp representing it was added to the container, and a foreign key on the container ID.

I want to fetch all the containers where the top item has a score of 5 or greater (which implies not returning empty containers). As containers act like stacks in this instance, the item with the highest 'added time' is considered the 'top' item.

At present, I'm using the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT name, container_id, score
  FROM items
  ORDER BY added_time DESC
) AS temptbl
GROUP BY container_id
HAVING score >= 5
```

This appears to give me the desired results, but it is incredibly slow when the number of items starts to increase - running the query on 8000 containers and 10000 items takes nearly 6 seconds on the MySQL console, which is too slow. Am I doing something obviously inefficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the inner select had a LEFT JOIN which was causing the slowdown - removing that reduced the query time to 0.01s. It means losing the information brought in by the join, but that can be filled in afterwards (final number of rows returned is 'small' so it doesn't matter if I have to run a query for each to replicate the effects of a LEFT JOIN).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT name, container_id, score
FROM items AS tb1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT container_id, Max(added_time) as added_time 
    FROM items GROUP BY tablename) as tb2 on 
    tb1.container_id = tb2.container_id AND tb1.added_time = tb2.added_time
WHERE score >= 5
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I would use MAX(score) - I want to find the containers where the top item has a given score. In other words, I need to find the top item for each container, then filter out the ones which don't match the criteria.

Comment: but to make it faster you can remove first items that doesn't mach criteria (score less than 5) and then search for top score in container.. As you described your problem: "I want to fetch all the containers where the top item has a score of 5 or greater"

Comment: I don't want the top (i.e. max()) score in the container, I want the score of the top (i.e. last added) item.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following. It relies on (container_id, added_id) being unique.

```
select *
  from (select container_id, max(added_time) as added_time
          from items
         group by container_id
       ) as topitems 
  join items on(topitems.container_id = items.container_id and 
                topitems.added_time   = items.added_time)
 where items.score >= 5;


select *
  from items a
 where score >= 5
   and (added_time) = (select max(b.added_time)
                         from items b
                        where a.container_id = b.container_id);
```